# how to adapt an app to work with node and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm after some direction about how to adapt a web app to work with express/mongodb/node.js Disclaimer: newbie to node, back-end server devlopment etc.

I have a web app which consists of a single html page, some css and a fair amount of javascript. Obviously, at this stage, everything runs client-side from the browser which is fine... but now I'm at the stage where I need to establish some server side features such as user account control, file upload and storage etc. As I am familiar with javascript, Node is an obvious choice for me.

From my research so far, it seems fairly straight forward to setup a simple express based server and I've found several hello-world tutorials to do just this, but most of these tutorials seem to be about starting a new app from scratch, and I'm left wondering what to do with all my existing javascript code... so my question is this.. Should I

1. leave the client side code as is and setup a simple server side node implementation that just talks to the database
2. Setup a server side node implementation, move all my javascript to the server and use some kind of templating to serve up content to the browser.
3. I'm completely missing the point here, and there's a way better way to do this

Pros and cons would be great
Thanks in advance, and go easy on a newbie!!

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more specifics, as the "best" way would depend on what is causing the change. What requirements are driving this change? If you are doing this as an exploration, then why not do all of the above, and note the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your app does, and what you are planning on using the database for. Simplest answer, is that you keep your current server set up as is, and set up a node server using express that has REST apis. You call those APIs from your pages, probably using ajax from jquery. Send off the call, parse the data in your page on return, and update the content of the page with the information received from the database, whether you are retrieving info to display, or writing info to the database, and simply displaying completion or error messages.

You can also move all your HTML to the node server. It's quite fine with serving up HTML, and then call your rest APIs from those pages, as though you had left them on your web server. Last thing to do would be to rewrite your pages in a templating language like jade or ejs that works with node, but this is only necessary if you have a need to format your pages dynamically on the server - that is, you're building parts of your pages up depending on what info is in the database, such as customer info that would change the look and feel of your pages.

It is typically more economical from a response time point of view, to update a page with javascript in the browser, and only changing those things that need to change with a small amount of data retrieved from the server, rather than rebuilding the entire page on the server every time someone updates something. Sometimes it's a mix - you format the base page on the server, then make changes in the browser with data retrieved from the server during the lifetime of the page.